# PHP if else statements

Tags: php

We have variable `$country`, it can give ~50 different values.

And variable `$id`.

What we should do is to give a value for `$id` corresponding to `$country` value, like:

```
if ($country = 'USA') { $id = 'usa_type'; }
else if ($country = 'France') { $id = 'france_type'; }
else if ($country = 'German') { $id = 'german_type'; }
else if ($country = 'Spain') { $id = 'spain_type'; }
...
...
...
else if ($country = 'Urugway') { $id = 'urugway_type'; }
else { $id = 'undefined'; }
```

`else if` statement repeats everytime, and other data is typical.

Is there a way to make this code shorter?

Like:

```
[france]:'france_type;
[england]:'england_type;
...
[else]:'undefined'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this important? Sometimes having longer code is worth the trade off if the shorter code is harder to understand and is so complex there is the potential for bugs to creep in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just create `$id` from `$country`:

```
$id = strtolower($country) . '_type';
```

If you first need to determine the validity of `$country`, put all your countries in an array, then use [`in_array`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to determine if `$country` is valid:

```
$countries = array('USA', 'France', 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Uruguay');
if (in_array($country, $countries)) {
    $id = strtolower($country) . '_type';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `switch` control structure . It will make your code shorter.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Switch is shorter? With all those break statements?

Answer (score 1):

looking at your example you could do something like

```
$id = strtolower($country) + '_type';
```

Answer (score 1):

Place all countries and codes in array like this:

```
$countries = array( "0" => array("country_name" => "usa", 
                                 "country_type" => "001" ) ,

                    "1" => array("country_name" => "uae", 
                                 "country_type" => "002" ),

                    -----------------------------
                    -----------------------------

                  );
```

Then use loop to compare country name and then get country id.

```
$country = "usa";

for( $i = 0; $i < count($countries); $i++ ) {
   if( $country == $countries[$i]["country_name"] ){
      $id = $countries[$i]["country_type"];
      break;
   }
}

echo $id;
```

Answer (score 1):

or you could create an array

```
$country_to_id = array(
  "USA" => "usa_type",
  "Spain" => "spain_type_or_whatever",
  ....
);
$country_id = (array_key_exists($country,$country_to_id)) ? $country_to_id[$country] : 'undefined';
```